# How To Style Choose File Button in Django Forms

Tags: django

[image]I have a form where users can upload files. But the button is kind of bland. It's a default html button. Do you have any way I can style that button using django forms?

This is the forms.py file

```py
class FileReaderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileReaderModel
        fields = ['file'] # I want this file(button) to be styled
```

This is my models.py file

```py
class FileReaderModel(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField()
    file_body = models.TextField()
    date_read = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_read']
        verbose_name_plural = "FileReaderModel"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file_name) + " File"
```

This is my file_reader.html file

```html
{% extends 'tools/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
    <title>The Tools Website | File Reader</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@700&display=swap');
        .encode {
            background-color: #060808;
            border-radius: 1em;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            color: white;
            transition: .5s;
        }
        .encode:hover {
            background-color: #121919;
        }
        h4 {
            font-family: Noto Sans JP;
        }
        .go_back {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    
    <h2>File Reader</h2>
    <br><br>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
    <br>
    {% if reader %}
        <pre>{{ reader }}</pre>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: Yes! I edited my post now!

Comment: what do you want it to look like? You have crispy-forms, and it should make it look okay.

Comment: The choose file button looks like the image i uploaded above! I wanted to change the way to looks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `attrs` parameter for Input Widget of your Django Form Field to add classes to your widget.

Create the form field explicitly and add the class to the attrs parameter:

```
class FileReaderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(
            attrs=["class": "<your css class goes here>"]
        )
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = FileReaderModel
        fields = ['file']
```

See the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Comment: This gives me an error. It says __init__() got an unexpected argument 'attrs'!

Comment: Totally my mistake. The widget should get the attrs, not the field. Edited my answer to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Following the above response(without trying it but still valid). In my case, I use Vanilla JavaScript if you know only basics but I'm little bit exprienced but not it does not require more experience for styling though.

In your casse.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="button_id">Submit</button>
    </form>

var my_button = document.getElementById("myH1");

my_button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

I just give another approacch that I used to use in my case.

Comment: var my_button = document.getElementById("button_id");

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I don't want to style the submit button. I want to style the choose file button!